# How to aggregate based on substrings in a column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a table in a format like this:

- NUMBER | COUNTRY
- 5      | Germany, US, China
- 1      | Germany, China, Japan
- 4      | China, India, Brazil
- 3      | Nigeria
- 8      | Brazil

I have another table with just countries:

- COUNTRY |
- Germany |
- China   |
- Brazil  |
- India   |
- Nigeria |
- US      |
- Japan   |

Now I want to sum aggregate NUMBER based on countries, so output would look something like:

- COUNTRY | SUM
- Germany | 6 <5 + 1>
- China   | 5 <1 + 4>
- Brazil  | 12
- India   | 4
- Nigeria | 3
- US      | 5
- Japan   | 1

The actual tables have many more columns and have 5000+ entries each.

My logic is to pick each country from the second table and do a LIKE with the second column of the first table and aggregate numbers for matches but I am not too sure how to implement this. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Try writing the SQL query to perform the operation yourself and post the table definitions & query with the results (maybe partial no. of rows from the results). So that people would be able to figure out the problem and give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like operator to join and aggregation function sum to get the total for each country.

```
  SELECT C.Country, SUM(CN.Number)
  FROM Table1 CN
  INNER JOIN Table2 C ON CN.Country LIKE CONCAT('%', C.Country,'%')
  GROUP BY C.Country
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an awful data format.  The first table should really be a junction/association table.  The SQL way of storing lists is as rows in a table, not as comma-delimited strings.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other people's really, really, really bad design decisions.  MySQL offers `find_set_set()` as a handy function in this case:

```
select c.country, sum(n.number)
from countries c left join
     numbers n
     on find_in_set(c.country, replace(n.country, ', ', ',')) > 0
group by c.country;
```